# How to increase the width of one column and decrease the width of the other one by the same length?

Tags: two-column

I'm diving a specific paragraph into two columns with the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left = 0.5in, right = 0.5in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\textbf{Theorem 1} \quad The distribution of $$\mathcal F_n: = \sup_{x \in \mathcal X} |F_n (x) - F(x)|$$ is known and the same for any DGP whose $F$ is \textbf{continuous}.

\textbf{Theorem 2} \quad If $F$ is \textbf{continuous} then for all $t > 0$, we have $$\mathbb P \left [\sqrt{n} \mathcal F_n \le t \right ] \longrightarrow H(t)= 1-2 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{j-1} e^{-2 j^{2} t^2}$$ where $H$ is the c.d.f of K-S distribution.

\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

and result

[image]

---

The paragraph would be more balance in my point of view if I can reduce the width of the first column by 2cm and thus increase the width of the second one by 2cm.

Could you please instruct me how to achieve this goal? Thank you so much!

Comment: Multicol only does equal sized columns (it stores the entire page as a single column, then splits it).  Paracol can handle different width collumns, but they are not linked (text will not flow across).  Flowfram can create different sized columns that are linked, but paragraphs which are split across the boundary will not match the column width.  I would stick with minipages.

Comment: Hi @JohnKormylo, `minipage` helps me achieve my goal of adjusting the width. Is it possible to insert a line separate the two columns?

Comment: you can use `\end{minipage}\hspace{5pt}\vrule width .5pt\hspace{5pt}\begin{minipage}...`  and make sure the width of your minipages allow the extra  10.5pt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a `tabularx` environment with two variable-width columns of type `X`. The requirement is that the individual relative widths -- here: 0.75 and 1.25 -- sum to the number of columns of type `X` -- here, 2. (If you would rather force the usual widths to have a ratio of 1:2, use 0.6667 and 1.3333 as the relative widths of the X columns.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[margin = 0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,tabularx,ragged2e}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash%
    \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L{0.75}|L{1.25} @{}} % 0.75+1.25=2.0
\textbf{Theorem 1} \quad The distribution of
\[
\mathcal{F}_n \coloneqq \sup_{x\in\mathcal X}\abs{F_n(x)-F(x)}
\] 
is known and the same for any DGP whose $F$ is \textbf{continuous}.
&
\textbf{Theorem 2} \quad If $F$ is \textbf{continuous} then for all $t > 0$, we have 
\[
\mathbb{P} [\sqrt{n} \mathcal F_n \le t ] \longrightarrow H(t)
    = 1- 2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j-1} e^{-2 j^2 t^2}
\] 
where $H$ is the cdf of the K-S distribution.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By default, width of the vertical divider line is `0.4pt`. If you need this width to be `1pt` instead, insert the instruction `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}` before `\noindent`.

Comment: Your typesetting is really beautiful :)

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility uses the `paracol` package and real theorem environments:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left = 0.5in, right = 0.5in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsfonts}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{theorem}
The distribution of
\[ \mathcal F_n: = \sup_{x \in \mathcal X} |F_n (x) - F(x)| \]
 is known and the same for any DGP whose $F$ is \textbf{continuous}.
\end{theorem}
\switchcolumn \stepcounter{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
 If $F$ is \textbf{continuous} then for all $t > 0$, we have
 \[ \mathbb P \left [\sqrt{n} \mathcal F_n \le t \right ] \longrightarrow H(t)= 1-2\smash[t]{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}}(-1)^{j-1} e^{-2 j^{2} t^2}, \]
  where $H$ is the c.d.f of K-S distribution.
\end{theorem}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may need the vwcol package. See `texdoc vwcol` for details. Unfortunately this package does not span pages

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left = 0.5in, right = 0.5in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{vwcol,amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={5.5cm,9.5cm}]
  \textbf{Theorem 1} \quad The distribution of $$\mathcal F_n: = \sup_{x \in \mathcal X} |F_n (x) - F(x)|$$ is known and the same for any DGP whose $F$ is \textbf{continuous}.

\textbf{Theorem 2} \quad If $F$ is \textbf{continuous} then for all $t > 0$, we have $$\mathbb P \left [\sqrt{n} \mathcal F_n \le t \right ] \longrightarrow H(t)= 1-2 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{j-1} e^{-2 j^{2} t^2}$$ where $H$ is the c.d.f of K-S distribution.
\end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```