# Odd interaction between tabularx and some list-like environments

Tags: tabularx, amsthm, ntheorem

After posting [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532543/5001) to the query [How to increase the width of one column and decrease the width of the other one by the same length?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532541/5001), I thought about how to generalize (and simplify) the OP's setting, e.g., by using explicit `theorem`-like environments in the two columns.

In the following MWE, which employs the `tabularx` and `amsthm` packages, things work fine. (The framelines in the screenshot indicate the edges of the text block.) In the first `tabularx` environment, the first column is narrower than the second, and in the second `tabularx` environment, the situation is reversed. In both environments, the filler text that makes up the body of the "theorems" occupies the full width of the cell:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsthm} 
%\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\noindent % First column is narrower than second:
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L{0.8} | L{1.2} @{}}
  \begin{theorem} \lipsum*[2] \end{theorem} &
  \begin{theorem} \lipsum*[2] \end{theorem}
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip\noindent % Now, first column is wider:
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L{1.2} | L{0.8} @{}}
  \begin{theorem} \lipsum*[2] \end{theorem} &
  \begin{theorem} \lipsum*[2] \end{theorem}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

**However**, if I comment out the instruction `\usepackage{amsthm}` and activate the instruction `\usepackage{ntheorem}` in the preceding MWE (and leave everything else unchanged), I get a rather different result: In the first `tabularx` environment, the text in the right-hand cell does not occupy the available horizontal space; in the second `tabularx` environment, both columns now take up the same width even as the width of the text in both cells is restricted to that of the second column.

**Question**: Have I encountered a bug in either `ntheorem` or `tabularx`, or did I set up the mechanism for generating `X` columns of varying widths incorrectly?

Some background information: The issue occurs with both TeXLive2019 and the current pre-release version of TeXLive2020. I use `tabularx 2020/01/15 v2.11c`, `amsthm 2017/10/31 v2.20.4`, and `ntheorem Version 1.33 <2011/08/15>`. AFAICT, the issue appears to be independent of the choice of document class.

[image]

Comment: It obviously can't be a bug in tabularx. let me look....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent (since 2017) versions of the `tabularx` manual have documented that setting `\hsize` isn't enough if you need to embed latex list environments (including trivlists like theorems), you need to set `\linewidth` to match.

[image]

using

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{ntheorem}
```

Comment: And I must confess to not having looked closely at the user guide of the `tabularx` package in a while. I just noticed that the 2020/01/15 version of the package's user guide explicitly recommends `>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X` -- and not just `>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X` as I seem to have remembered from earlier versions.

Comment: @Mico oh b@@@r and you almost made me admit to an error in the doc (I did not of course actually look at the doc just now:-)

Comment: @Mico tools changes.txt says 2017-09-28  David Carlisle  <latex-bugs@latex-project.org>

 * tabularx.dtx: set \linewidth as well as \hsize in the column
 widths documentation.  I shall edit the answer to say it is user error not a failing in the doc!

Comment: Well, I've gone ahead and modified/corrected about a dozen answers from the past year or so which used only `\hsize=#1\hsize` but not `\linewidth=\hsize}` as well.